# Adicionar nós a lista encadeada usando loop

Tags: c, loop, struct, lista-encadeada

Não encontrei nenhuma questão parecida, caso tenha, por favor, indique e eu apago o post.
Como criar um lista encadeada que eu possa utilizar um for loop para colocar os nós na lista. Eu to usando duas estruturas, uma pra lista em si, e uma pro nó. Se eu criar uma variável do tipo node para cada nó funciona.

```
typedef struct List
{
    int size;
    struct Node *mainNode;
} list;

typedef struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
} node;
```

Loop que não esta funcionando:

```
list myList = newEmptyList();
node *nodeArray[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    nodeArray[i]->value = i;
    addNode(&myList, nodeArray[i]);
}
```

Função addNode:

```
void addNode(list *targetList, node *nodeToAdd)
{
    node *lastNode;
    if (targetList->size == 0)
    {
        targetList->size++;
        targetList->mainNode = nodeToAdd;
    }
    else
    {
        lastNode = getNode(*targetList, targetList->size - 1);
        targetList->size++;
        lastNode->next = nodeToAdd;
    }

    printf("Node added.\nNew list size: %d\n", targetList->size);
    system("pause");
    
}
```

Função getNode:

```
node * getNode(list targetList, int index)
{
    Node* currentNode = NULL;

    if (index >= targetList->size || index < 0) return currentNode;

    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            currentNode = targetList->mainNode;
        }
        else
        {
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
        }
    }
    return currentNode;     
}
```

Output:
*Node added.

New list size: 1

Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .

Node added.

New list size: 2

Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .*
Especificamente depois do dois, o programa para de uma forma abrupta.

Comment: Poste um programa completo, compilável.

Comment: Adicionei a função getNode, eu queria resumir para não fazer um post muito grande, e a função main é apenas aquele loop mesmo, espero que o post tenha melhorado.

Comment: Além disso havia um erro na função getNode, muito obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É difícil entender só com parte do programa o que está acontecendo.

Sem ler o código de `getNode()` e do resto do programa fica difícil.

A partir do que postou, parece muito complicado.

#### sobre a estrutura

A convenção em C é reservar a primeira letra em maiúscula para aos tipos definidos, porque assim diferencia esses tipos das variáveis normais. Você usou `List` por exemplo em uma struct que em geral é anônima no typedef. E usou `list` para o nome, e assim perdeu essa diferenciação. Apenas o nó precisa de um nome porque tem uma referência interna a ele mesmo na estrutura. Compare com o exemplo a seguir.

É muito mais complicado programar uma lista com ponteiros para um lado só. Se não precisa realmente disso use ponteiros para os dois lados. É o simples. Com ponteiro para um único lado a todo momento tem que se reposicionar, ou então ficar salvando ponteiros pelo programa. Usando ponteiros para os dois lados e deixando na lista ponteiros para o início e para o fim da lista tudo fica mais fácil: percorrer, remover, inserir...

E em geral o dado é `void*` porque fica genérico e pode usar sempre as mesmas funções.

#### de volta ao programa

Considere essa estrutura para uma lista de `int`

```
typedef int     Data; // can be anything

typedef struct st_node
{
    Data            value;
    struct st_node* next;

}   Node;

typedef struct
{
    int     size;
    Node*   start;

}   List;
```

E compare: `Lista` tem `Node` e `Node` tem `Data`. Como eu disse, devia ser um ponteiro, e se possível `void`, genérico.

#### um exemplo completo

Vou te mostrar um **exemplo** que usa essas estruturas e essas funções:

```
    void        add_data_b(Data* data, List* l);
    void        add_data_e(Data* data, List* l);
    List*       create_list();
    void        show_list(List*, const char*);
```

escritas do jeito comum de fazer isso. `add_data_b()` insere no início da lista e, claro, `add_data_e()` insere no final. `show_list()` aceita uma mensagem opcional como parâmetro.

**O exemplo:**

- insere de 13 a 24 no final da lista
- insere de 12 a 1 nessa ordem no início da lista
- usa um `for()` para cada caso e assim você tem exemplos de como fazer o que quer
- assim a lista final deve ter 24 elementos, de 1 a 24

#### saida do exemplo

```
Teste: inseridos de 13 a 24 no fim da lista

        => 12 elementos

  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
  23  24

Teste: inseridos de 12 a 1 no inicio da lista

        => 24 elementos

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24
```

#### O programa completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int     Data; // can be anything

typedef struct st_node
{
    Data            value;
    struct st_node* next;

}   Node;

typedef struct
{
    int     size;
    Node*   start;

}   List;

    void        add_data_b(Data* data, List* l);
    void        add_data_e(Data* data, List* l);
    List*       create_list();
    void        show_list(List*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    List* l = create_list();

    // insere no fim
    for (int i = 13; i <= 24; i+=1) add_data_e(&i, l);
    show_list(l, "Teste: inseridos de 13 a 24 no fim da lista");

    // insere no inicio
    for (int i = 12; i >= 1; i-=1) add_data_b(&i, l);
    show_list(l, "Teste: inseridos de 12 a 1 no inicio da lista");
    return 0;
}


void add_data_b(Data* data, List* l)
{  // insert at list start
    // we need a new node, anyway...
    Node* new  = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new->value = *data;
    new->next  = NULL;
    // list may be empty
    if (l->size == 0)
    {
        l->start = new;
        l->size  = 1;
        return;
    }
    new->next = l->start;
    l->start = new;
    l->size += 1;
}


void add_data_e(Data* data, List* l)
{  // insert at the end
    // we need a new node, anyway...
    Node* new  = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new->value = *data;
    new->next  = NULL;
    // list may be empty
    if (l->size == 0)
    {
        l->start = new;
        l->size  = 1;
        return;
    }
    Node* p = l->start;
    while (p->next != NULL) p = p->next;
    p->next = new;
    l->size += 1;
}

List* create_list()
{ 
    List* new = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    new->size = 0;
    new->start = NULL;
    return new;
}

void show_list(List* l, const char* message)
{
    if (message != NULL) printf("%s\n\n", message);
    printf("\t=> %d elementos\n\n", l->size);
    int nc = 0;
    Node* n  = l->start;
    for (int i = 0; i < l->size; i += 1)
    {   // mostra um por um
        printf("%4d", n->value);
        n = n->next;
        nc += 1;
        if (nc == 10)
        {   // mostra 10 por coluna
            printf("\n");
            nc = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Eu pensei que tinha como fazer sem usar as funções de alocação dinâmica, mas parece que me equivoquei, muito obrigado.

Comment: pode escrever sem usar `free()/malloc()`. Use um vetor e use os índices como ponteiros. Só que vai ter que declarar todos de uma vez, claro: Será um vetor de nós. Quer ver um exemplo? É a mesma coisa. Só é muito mais rápido e muito menos conveniente, em especial na hora de remover algum nó.